# How to get total result count from entity manager query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am working on pagination using spring boot. I am trying get total count of results from entity manager query for the pagination. For that I am getting maxresults to show from query, but how can i get total count of results.Please tell me i am new to enity manager.

```
    @Override
public List<User> getsearchresults(String result) {

    String query = "FROM User WHERE (education = :education) OR (city = :city)";

    return em
                .createQuery(query,User.class)
                .setParameter("education",education)
                .setParameter("city",city)
                .setMaxResults(5)
                .getResultList();
 }
```

this is how i write query which returns results but i need total number of result count.How can i do that plesase help me.

Comment: This info is lost when you `setMaxResults`. Could you not do that and then get all the items as objects in the `List` then you've got the count (`List.size()`) and then filter it in code instead?

Comment: @tomgeraghty3 i write 2 functions with the same query twice, one with maxresults without maxresults to get list size. i know this is not best way but it worked for me.thanks for hint.